# Mapping of 1:m relationships

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, model

What is the best way to map a `1:m` relationship?

For example.

---

A database of songs. We have the tables:

- `Songs`
- `Artists`
- `Albums`

Let's say we need to fetch all albums. A song has a foreign key to `Albums`
What I used to do is get a list of all the albums:

```
SELECT * FROM `Albums`;
```

And then map it to an object.
Next, I'd make a for-each loop though every album and make a new SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM `Songs` WHERE albumId = album;
```

Then I'd map it again.

---

This is obviously overkill.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Just a doubt, in mySQL you can't use table joins?

Comment: @JhonatasKleinkauff Sure, I guess this was actually a bad example. This is not m:m, let me rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes most sense for an `Album` to have an `ICollection<Song> Songs` and for the `Artist` to have an `ICollection<Album> Albums`

Your queries should be straightforward after this point.

> Let's say we need to fetch all albums.

`SELECT * FROM Albums`

> An albums has a foreign key to Songs

I think a `Song` should actually have a Foreign Key to an `Album` because it uniquely defines a `Song` which could be on multiple Albums.

> My question was actually terribly phrased. Can you make an example of
>   such a query? Like in the question: Get all the albums with the
>   associated songs.

`SELECT a.Album_Name, s.Song_Name FROM Albums a JOIN Songs s ON a.Album_Name = s.Album_Name`

Comment: My question was actually terribly phrased. Can you make an example of such a query? Like in the question: Get all the albums with the associated songs.

Comment: I see, for mapping one could use a Dictionary with a key of the album id. I guess this is pretty helpful, thanks!

Comment: "I think a Song should actually have a Foreign Key to an Album because it uniquely defines a Song which could be on multiple Albums"

Of course you're right, this was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to fully populate all your model objects then you'd be better off getting all your songs, artists and albums and cacheing them locally.

Normally, though, inflating your model object will happen when the adidtional information is required,e.g. when a user selects Show Song Details..., at which point the artist and album info can be rerieved.